# Python openpyxl error

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to open a file using Python and paste query results out of Oracle in to a specific sheet.  I found a way to do with with xlswriter but that is not the right tool for the job.

I can get my query to execute and append to a list. I have both strings and integers in the result.  I cannot get this to transfer to an excel file. Any help would be great.

The error I'm getting is:

```
line 201, in _bind_value
   raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0} to Excel".format(value)) 

ValueError: Cannot convert ('20 GA GV-CS-CT-DRY-G90 60xC COIL', 2, 848817, 982875, 1.15793510261929) to Excel
```

Code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import openpyxl

con = cx_Oracle.connect('example', 'example', "example")
cur = con.cursor()

heatmap_data = []

statement = """ select * from example"""

cur.arraysize = 2000
cur.execute(statement)

for result in cur:
    heatmap_data.append(result)

con.close()

file = "path/Test.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

row = 1
col = 1


for rowNum in range(2, len(heatmap_data)):
    ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = heatmap_data[rowNum]
    row =+ 1

wb.save(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with the following code:

```
row = 1


    for i in (heatmap_data):
        print(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4])
        ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value = (i[0])
        ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = (i[1])
        ws.cell(row=row, column=3).value = (i[2])
        ws.cell(row=row, column=4).value = (i[3])
        ws.cell(row=row, column=5).value = (i[4])
        row += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe openpyxl doesn't convert iterables (which is what looks to be passed) to `ws.cell.value`.

Try:
`for rowNum, data in enumerate(heatmap_data):
    ws.cell(row=rowNum + 2, column=col).value = ", ".join(data[rowNum])
    # Noticed the range you're choosing skips the first 2 values of your data.
    # Looks like you're not incrementing the column. Meh. Guess not.`

Heh.